# Python program will not open the website. All that happens is a black flash

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to make a program that opens up a random page in Wikipedia when ran. For some reason when I run the program nothing happens expect the terminal window flashes once. This is weird because I have programs that open up YouTube and W3Schools with no problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver

# Set up the Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Open a random Wikipedia page by appending "Special:Random" to the base URL
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")

# Keep the window open until it is closed manually
driver.close()
```

I expected a random wiki page to open up but instead the program just flashes once.

Answer (score 0):

it flashes it as you are closing the driver right away using `driver.close()`.

if you want to see it for a couple of seconds add sleep code or anything that will keep the driver from closing:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# Set up the Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()


# Open a random Wikipedia page by appending "Special:Random" to the base URL
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random")

time.sleep(5)    

# Keep the window open until it is closed manually
driver.close()
```

Comment: For some reason it is still flashing once. I modified the code to sleep for 30 seconds and still nothing happens.

Comment: i took the above code and added the sleep and it looked ok
so im guessing it is an environment issue.

which python, selenium versions are you using?
running on a virtual env?